# Why is chrome's print preview and printed view is different ? [HTML - CSS]

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, printing

I have a demo angular project which has basic text and table inside as below.There is print button which is calling `window.print()` to make the page printed with applied styling.

```
 printPage() {
    window.print();
  }
```

css:

```
 @media print {
      @page {
         size: landscape;
         margin: 0;
      }
  }
```

My demo project link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxlcna?file=src/print/print.component.ts
[image]

My aim is being able to print this table landscaped exactly how it seems on the web page without any crops.^

After print button clicked preview on chrome's print dialog looks great as below

[image]

Unfortunately after print, result is not as expected.As you can see there are crops from left and right sides of the paper.Although my other attempts to set margin:0 padding:0 stylings didn't work.How can I print exactly as same as what I'm seeing on HTML page?

I tried also this kind of styling

```
@media print {
  * {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! *"My demo project link : ____"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your example and it's a problem related with the printer. Some printers have a "non-printable margin" by default so there is no way to print on the edges.

The user could be change manually if there are some options for scaling the document but it would be a bad solution.

My solution would be adding some margins in the CSS for the print media. For example, in this case, I 've added a left and right margin and everything it's printed correctly.

```
.designed__table {
  width: 100%;
  td,
  th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 0px 10px;
  }
}
.print-container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately